# Help me Identify Strange and Bizarre Fantasy Artist, World Was Similar to Dragons Lair Game

Tags: story-identification, art

This may not be the best place to ask, but I was trying to find artwork by a fantasy artist I remember very little about. I know his art was similar to Don Bluth’s work on the famous Dragons Lair games, but far more surreal, (flying treasure chests with eye-balls and weird things like that). I want to say it was as cartoonish as his was, but I think it did have a hint of serious tone and look of Frank Frazetta layered in. Lastly it all may have been part of a fantasy series or comic book. I wish I knew more, and it’s driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: I believe I saw his work recently, (last few months), in an article about the artist on gizmodo or io9 however, I can’t seem to find it anywhere after scouring for hours.

Comment: When did you see this? Was it in a book? Online? Album cover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I believe I have found it. It appears to be artist Paul Kidby’s Discworld Series book covers and artwork, as well as others imitating his style and creating more Discworld art. Thanks for hunting with me, glad to have my mind at ease. (Guess the chest had lots of feet not eyes...) [image][image][image]

Comment: If you want to merge your accounts you can find instructions [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Thanks! Just did that following your link

Comment: Good to know that link actually does something :)

Comment: Neither of these images are by Paul Kidby.  The first is by Shayu Dan and the second is by Josh Kirby.

Comment: Added one of his at the bottom, thought the first was his, my bad, but, I did say also inspired works too.

Answer (score 4):

Flying eyeballs made me think of Rick Griffin, or possibly Jim Woodring, but then I remembered Vaughn Bode which might fit the fantasy world setting better (Vaughn Bode's Cobalt 90 was a major influence on Ralph Bakshi's Wizards)

Comment: Word to the wise, depending on your search engine of choice, Vaughn Bode's art may turn up NSFW.

Comment: These artists are great thanks for sharing, and so close to what I was thinking